# Updating composer library after files deployed to shared production server

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan, intervention

I created a website using laravel.

I uploaded the site to my shared server, and site was running fine.

After that I had to add a library called Intervention. In local, I used this command and everything is working fine.

```
php composer.phar require intervention/image
```

I made changes in files and everything is working fine in local.

Now, I need to upload the updated files. So rather than deleting whole online folder, and re-uploading, I just want to upload changed files (I know the controller, view files that were changed).

But, as it is a shared server there is no way or place to execute composer update command or get that one library (thus now I am getting intervention Image class not found error).

So, what would be ideal thing to do in this case?

The easiest one maybe delete the whole folder and upload it again but the files are almost 500mb so do not want that.

Any suggestions to handle this situation? (updating composer libraries after deployment)

Comment: Your life will be *massively* easier if you find a host that gives you SSH access. This'd be a nice simple `composer install`.

Comment: Simple solution, use a host that has a CLI or SSH, using this type of hosting is useless for this type of applications. Use AWS, Google Cloud, Digital Ocean, but not a hosting that does not give FULL access to the rented space/power. And you use GIT to share stuff, not FTP or anything similar. Of course once you get the new code using GIT you must run `composer install` again and run any other command that seems fit

Comment: Please share more details. How is your problem related to Composer, Laravel, or Intervention? What have you tried to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

Not really a php or laravel question, but if you're using ftp to upload there's usually an option to only upload changed files.

For example in filezilla you can set the over-ride option here:

[image: filezilla dialogue]

Comment: so what about the new package in vendor?

Comment: ultimately they are just files that you can copy. With dependencies it's probably safer to delete the entire package and replace it.